# Removing child nodes from DOM table removing only alternate children

Tags: php, html, dom

I am using PHP and I have an HTML string that contains a string. I need to delete all rows of the table (In reality, there would be some logic to check if to delete the row but for now I am deleting all the rows).

I am trying to delete all the rows from the table but only alternate rows are getting deleted.

```php
$html_string = <<<HTML
<div class="my-table-div">
   <div class="clear"></div>
   <div class="table-wrap">
      <table id="my-table" class="my-class">
         <thead>
            <tr>
               <th class="manage-column" scope="col">Col1</th>
               <th class="manage-column" scope="col">Col2</th>
               <th class="manage-column" scope="col">Col3</th>
               <th class="manage-column" scope="col">Col4</th>
               <th class="manage-column" scope="col">Col5;</th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td></td>
               <td>Item 1</td>
               <td></td>
               <td></td>
               <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td></td>
               <td>Item 2</td>
               <td></td>
               <td></td>
               <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td></td>
               <td>Item 3</td>
               <td></td>
               <td></td>
               <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td></td>
               <td>Item 4</td>
               <td></td>
               <td></td>
               <td></td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </div>
</div>
HTML

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html_string);
$table = $doc->getElementsByTagName('table')[0];
$trs = $table->getElementsByTagName('tr');
for( $x=1; $x<count($trs); $x++ ) {
      $trs[$x]->parentNode->removeChild($trs[$x]);
}

//var_dump($doc->saveHTML()); // to check output of the above code
```

Actual Result after doing above:

```
Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4    Col5
        Item 2          
        Item 4
```

Expected Result:

```
Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4    Col5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You problem is about understanding this part of code

```
$trs[$x]->parentNode->removeChild($trs[$x]);
```

When you remove an element in this way the element will remove from the `$trs` and then reindex in indexes for example look and this example

```
elements
    1 -> sub element 1
    2 -> sub element 2
    3 -> sub element 3
```

When you remove the first one it will be like this

```
elements
    1 -> sub element 2
    2 -> sub element 3
```

And now you again need to remove the element with index 1 
so you should change this code to sth like this

```
$trs[1]->parentNode->removeChild($trs[1]);
```

And your final code will be like this

```php
$html_string = '
<div class="my-table-div">
   <div class="clear"></div>
   <div class="table-wrap">
      <table id="my-table" class="my-class">
         <thead>
            <tr>
               <th class="manage-column" scope="col">Col1</th>
               <th class="manage-column" scope="col">Col2</th>
               <th class="manage-column" scope="col">Col3</th>
               <th class="manage-column" scope="col">Col4</th>
               <th class="manage-column" scope="col">Col5;</th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td></td>
               <td>Item 1</td>
               <td></td>
               <td></td>
               <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td></td>
               <td>Item 2</td>
               <td></td>
               <td></td>
               <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td></td>
               <td>Item 3</td>
               <td></td>
               <td></td>
               <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td></td>
               <td>Item 4</td>
               <td></td>
               <td></td>
               <td></td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </div>
</div>';

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html_string);
$table = $doc->getElementsByTagName('table')[0];
$trs = $table->getElementsByTagName('tr');
$trCount = count($trs) - 1;
for( $x=0; $x < $trCount; $x++ ) {
      $trs[1]->parentNode->removeChild($trs[1]);
}

print_r($doc->saveHTML());
```

Comment: If my answer helped you with your question, I would appreciate it if you upvote my answer and choose it as the best answer as you wish.